# Is it possible to bind a struct to an interface in Unity?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, unity-container, ioc-container

I want configure Unity to resolve an interface, say `ITest`, to a struct, say `struct Test`. So far I have next:

```
<unity>
    <containers>
        <container>
            <types>
                <type
                    type="my.ITest, asm" 
                    mapTo="my.Test, asm">
                </type>
            </types>
        </container>
    </containers>
</unity>
```

but I'm getting next error:

```
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "my.ITest", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type Test cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.
At the time of the exception, the container was:    
Resolving my.Test,(none) (mapped from my.ITest,(none))
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Unity supports only binding of classes.](http://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/268800#post656993)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use Unity to construct a struct; because a struct is a value type, Activator.CreateInstance is going to blow chunks when trying to create it (because of the interface).

For example:

```
 var item = Activator.CreateInstance<Test>();
```

Would throw an exception "Cannot create an instance of an interface". Internally, Unity is probably using Activator.CreateInstance somewhere down the chain (I've been looking through Unity's code plex for a little while now), and that's where it will die.

I'd suggest changing to a class implementation instead of a struct.

Comment: Why would `Activator.CreateInstance` not be able to create a struct?

Comment: I tested this out; when the struct has an interface on it, the CreateInstance call fails. Unknown why.

Comment: `Int32` implements a number of interfaces and that works fine.

Comment: Dont know what to tell you. I did a simple example; `public struct ConcreteSomething : ISomething { }` and then called `Activator.CreateInstance<ConcreteSomething>` and it threw an error.

Comment: @tejs - what version of .net?         interface I { }
        struct S : I{ }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            I o = Activator.CreateInstance<S>();
        } works fine for me (.net4)

Comment: The problem is that I need a struct. I use it as search criteria and key in cache, so struct is much more suitable.

Comment: @Tejs: Actually `Activator.CreateInstance<ConcreteSomething : ISomething>()` works for me